# How to cast properties to boolean (deep)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to cast every type to `boolean` or `object`

```
type CastDeep<T, K = boolean> = {
  [P in keyof T]: K extends K[]
    ? K[]
    : T[P] extends ReadonlyArray<K>
      ? ReadonlyArray<CastDeep<K>>
      : CastDeep<T[P]>
}
```

```
interface ITest {
  city: {
    name: string,
  }
}
```

Expected result:

```
excludeProps<ITest>({
   city: true,
});
```

or

```
excludeProps<ITest>({
 city: {
  name: true
 },
});
```

Current error message:

```
  19     name: string,
           ~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'name' which is declared here on type 'CastDeep<{ name: string; }, boolean>'
```

Comment: Why not simply `{ [key:string]: boolean | object; }` ?

Comment: I want to have it deep

Comment: *"Expected result...or..."* Um...which is it?

Comment: Just to be clear: Doing this kind of typecasting has no effect whatsoever on your objects. It's purely a typecasting exercise (compile-time static type stuff), not a runtime thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wanted to point out, I may want to exclude whole `city` object or specified property `name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found a solution

```
export type ICastDeep<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: boolean | ICastDeep<T[P]>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone for helping, @Maryannah posted a simple solution which gave me an idea

Comment: Glad I could help anyway :)

Comment: @Maryannah - Your recursive thing was the key insight here.